# iMac with Radeon 4670 HD wont' boot

Tags: boot, 16.04, radeon, mac

I've just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my iMac 21.5 mid 2010.

I've followed this guide:

http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/how-install-linux-on-mac-3637265/

The installation went perfectly, but when I rebooted it gave me the "Remove installation problem" error . So I manually rebooted my machine. I then received a purple screen and then a totally black screen appears. After a few seconds I heard the sound of ubuntu (the drums thing) but nothing appears on screen.

Does anyone know what the problem is and how can I fix it? 
It's my first installation of Ubuntu and I don't know what to do...

Comment: Were you able to boot from usb/dvd/cd and the os worked successfully by displaying your desktop on screen?

Comment: Yes, Booting from the USB and inserting "nomodeset" everything worked fine.

Comment: try using nomodeset when booting your hard drive install and see if the desktop pops up